# Flip the underbrace

Tags: math-mode

Is there a way to flip this \underbrace in the code so that it stays on the same place (under the V but points towards it not away from it as it does right now.

```
v(t) = Re \{ \underbrace{V}_{V_o e^{j \omega t}} e^{j \phi} \}
```

Thank you advance.

Btw, how do you write LaTeX code here directly? Sorry, I am new here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you didn't want the understacked material to affect the main equation's spacing, then the `stackengine` package's `\useanchorwidth` parameter is helpful.

Here, I stack the embraced commentary under the `V`, but tell `stackengine` to use the horizontal size of the `V` "anchor" to determine the horizontal space allocated for the overall stack.  If I set `\useanchorwidth` to `{F}`, the answer will look much like the other answers given.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$v(t) = Re \{ \stackunder{V}{\overbrace{\scriptstyle V_o e^{j \omega t}}\,} e^{j \phi} \} $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the original `\underbrace` as the starting point of your definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\def\downunderbrace#1{\mathop {\vtop {\m@th \ialign {##\crcr $\hfil \displaystyle {#1}\hfil $\crcr 
\noalign {\kern 3\p@ \nointerlineskip }
%\upbracefill 
\downbracefill 
\crcr \noalign {\kern 3\p@ }}}}\limits}
\makeatother


\[
v(t) = Re \{ \underbrace{V}_{V_o e^{j \omega t}} e^{j \phi} \} 
\]

\[
v(t) = Re \{ \downunderbrace{V}_{V_o e^{j \omega t}} e^{j \phi} \} 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes, using [`abraces`](http://ctan.org/pkg/abraces):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abraces}
\begin{document}
\[ v(t) = Re \{ \underbrace{V}_{V_o e^{j \omega t}} e^{j \phi} \} \]

\[ v(t) = Re \{ \aunderbrace[L1U1R]{V}_{V_o e^{j \omega t}} e^{j \phi} \} \]
\end{document}
```

`L1U1R` implies a `L`eft-down end, 1 segment of horizontal fill, an `U`pward facing cusp, 1 segment of horizontal fill and a `R`ight-down end.

Comment: Exactly what I looked for. Thank you so much!